# What is the difference between $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$?

Tags: notation, set-theory, infinity

The book I'm using says that the cardinality of a set $X$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $|X| = |\alpha|$.  So then $\omega = \aleph_0$, but 
$\omega + \omega \ne \omega$, while $\aleph_0 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.  What am I missing?

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is a cardinal number, whereas $\omega$ is an ordinal number.

Comment: @Peter: For many of us $\omega$ is both an ordinal number *and* a cardinal number.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is $\omega+\omega$ a cardinal number too even if we use ordinal arithmetic? If so it is equal to $\omega$.

Comment: @MattS: If $+$ denotes ordinal addition, then of course $\omega+\omega$ is not a cardinal: it’s not an initial ordinal. If $+$ denotes cardinal addition, then $\omega+\omega=\omega$.

Comment: @MattS: No -- since the ordinal $\omega+_o\omega = \omega\times_o 2$ is not an _initial ordinal_, it is not also a cardinal. In the usual ZFC-based development, all cardinals are (represented by) ordinals, but not all ordinals are cardinals.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re talking about two different operations. In $\omega+\omega\ne\omega$ you’re talking about ordinal addition; in $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ you’re talking about cardinal addition. When you consider $\omega$ as a cardinal number and perform cardinal arithmetic on it, $\omega+\omega=\omega$. Similarly, the ordinal sum $\omega_1+\omega$ is the ordinal $\omega_1+\omega$, not the ordinal $\omega_1$, but the cardinal sum $\omega_1+\omega$ is the cardinal $\omega_1$.

Those of us who use the $\omega_\alpha$ notation for both ordinals and cardinals must either rely on context to distinguish ordinal and cardinal arithmetic or explicitly specify which one is being used.

Comment: Good to have you back Brian. (I like reading your answers and I appreciate your perspective on meta)

Comment: @Rustyn: Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In standard set theory, they are the same set, but seen from different perspectives. The notation $\omega$ emphasizes that it is an *ordinal number*, whereas the notation $\aleph_0$ emphasizes its role as a *cardinal number*.

Now whereas $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$ are two different notations for the same set, $+$ and $+$ is the *same notation* being used for two *different operations*. The meaning of "$+$" depends on whether we're adding ordinals or cardinals.

Some books use $+_o$ and $+_c$ for ordinal and cardinal addition, but in everyday semi-informal mathematics we just write $+$ for both and let it depend on context which one is meant. (Which is one reason why it is useful to have two different notations for $\mathbb N$ used as an ordinal and cardinal, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

$\omega$ is a well ordered set, while $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of that set. $|\omega|=\aleph_0$. As I've been informed, since $\omega$ is an initial ordinal, it is also considered a cardinal number, so indeed $\omega=\aleph_0$, and $|\omega|=\aleph_0$. However, when we use ordinal arithmetic $|\omega+\omega|=\aleph_0$ as well, even though $\omega+\omega\neq \omega$.

Comment: @Andres: I think it is a bit harsh to call it nonstandard. It is not uncommon in elementary introductions to cardinality to consider cardinal numbers to be abstract concepts that are not necessarily represented by concrete sets. Equalities and inequalities between cardinal numbers are then interpreted as abbreviations for existence of certain bijections etc. This approach is technically simpler when writing for an audience that don't need to consider cardinal numbers first-class objects (and also allows most of the development to be choice-agnostic).

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, it is not harsh. (How is the word "non-standard" harsh?) It is not meant to be anything other than what it said: Set theorists agree on the meaning of these symbols, and it is not the one stated in the original wording of the answer. In the early 20th century there was a distinction between the symbols, with ordinals being order types rather than sets, etc. Nowadays, in set theory, the meaning is settled and the conventions are well-established (again, not a judgement call, just a fact), even among those of us who may be interested in the choiceless setting.

Comment: (@HenningMakholm That said, naturally different fields, even some that overlap heavily with set theory, use different conventions. But the question is tagged [tag:set-theory].)